# "menu icon is getting displaced when i toggle my menu icon" how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a menu toggle bar in my web for mobile devices but getting an error. The toggle icon gets displaced when I open it. Here is an example:

**when menu is off:**

[image]

**when menu is on: See the menu icon change the position and gets displaced to left side, How can I fix it ?**

[image]

**Here is the source code:**

```bash
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

    <style>
    *{
        background-color: #000;
    }

    #menu {
    display: none;
    }
  
    #menu > i {
    
    transition: 0.4s;
    text-align: right;
    color: #f0f8ff;
    font-size: 25px;  
    }

    #navbar{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 50px;

}


@media (max-width: 480px){
    #menu {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        /* text-align: right; */
        float: right;
        /* margin-right: -174px; */
        margin-top: 35px;
        margin-right: 35px;
      }
    
      #navbar {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
      }
    
      #navbar.open {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 38px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        height: fit-content;
        position: sticky;
        z-index: 100;

      }
    
      #navbar.open a {
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 22px;
        padding: 10px;
        
      }

      #nav_container{
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;

      }

      #left-heading{
        font-size: 30px;
        padding-top: 23px;
        padding-left: 15px;
      }
 
      #background1 > h1{
        font-size: 40px;
        margin-top: 245px;
        padding-top: 0px;
      }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav_container" >
        <nav id="navbar">
          <a href="projects.html"><i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i> Projects</a>
          <a href="about.html"><i class="fas fa-rocket"></i> About me</a>
          <a href=""><i class="fas fa-wrench"></i> Services</a>
          <a href=""><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Contact me</a>
        </nav>

        <div id="menu">
           <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
                 <a href="1st_webpage.html" id="left-heading"> company</a>
                </div>

          <script>
            const Menu = document.querySelector('#menu');
            const navbar = document.querySelector('#navbar');

            Menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
            navbar.classList.toggle('open');
        });

        </script>      

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have given id **navbar & menu both float right**. Those are siblings of same parent container which is nav_container. When initially navbar is not there your menu icon renders only, it gets its perfect position after applying margin but the moment navbar populates it goes to right most side & push menu icon in left side because **in DOM navbar comes first that's the reason it gets float right first.**

In order to fix this lets give parent container(nav_container) position relative & also to menu icon give the position absolute, 10px from right side & z-index 100.
Add the below css in your media queries section-

```css
#nav_container{
  position: relative;
 }
#menu{
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   z-index: 100;
   display: block;
   top: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: but i want that `nav_container` a sticky element, after applying `position: relative;` it isn't a being sticky at the top

Comment: just add one div inside nav_container & add your current children inside this new container & give this container position relative. Keep your nav_container sticky.